# Catalyst Sidebar

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, mac-catalyst

I'm working through this tutorial from apple. I am getting stuck on the shown below, I keep getting an error, `Use of unresolved identifier 'window'`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let splitViewController = window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem

    // Add a translucent background to the primary view controller.
    splitViewController.primaryBackgroundStyle = .sidebar

    splitViewController.delegate = self

    return true
}
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. Catalyst apps are by default Window Scene-based. You don’t have a window here. Apple tutorials are outdated.

The solution is to create your own window and fill it in didFinish...

The more correct way is to add your code to delegate of scenes.